# "It was Bob who ate my biscuits" <--Why does this relative clause break all the rules?

Tags: relative-clauses, clefts

The following sentences are from [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-12/session-1) [just to give a source showing that these sentences are all grammatically correct].

1. It was Rob that/who ate my biscuits. (not Catherine)
2. It was my biscuits that/which Rob ate. (not my sandwiches)
3. Was it Rob that/who ate my biscuits?

The list could goes on. My point is, these relative clauses are not defining relative clauses.

In a defining relative clause, we have an antecedent and a relative clause where the relative clause helps the listener identify who or what the antecedent refers to:

4. That's the man who ate my biscuits.
5. Look for the elephant who's carrying the umbrella.
6. The doctor that treated me was a woman.

In (4) the phrase *who ate my biscuits* tells us which man we are talking about. The clause *who's carrying an umbrella* identifies which elephant to look for. The clause *that treated me* helps identify which doctor was a woman. And we see also that in some sense the relative clause *restricts* our interpretation of the antecedent. For these reasons, such clauses are also sometimes referred to as 'restrictive'.

Because of the way these work, we cannot use such relative clauses when the antecedent is already known or identifiable. For example (7) below only works if you have more than one father:

(7) Yesterday, I met your father that bought me a drink.

---

**Further information**

I've been told in comments that grammars like CGEL, which recognise that these types of clause in (4-6) are normally defining/restrictive, call them 'integrated' relative clauses. They note that integrated relatives form a constituent with antecedent noun phrases, and are tightly integrated into the construction they appear in.

However, as @BillJ and others inform me, the relative clauses in (1-3) do *not* form a constituent with their antecedent.

---

**The question**

Back to the thrust of my question. In (1-3), the relative clauses do not explain or define who *Rob* is. The listener already knows who *Rob* is. So unlike the defining relative clauses in (4-6),they do not restrict our understanding of the reference of the noun phrase *Rob.* And as shown in (7) unlike with defining/restrictive/integrated relative clauses we *can* use the relative clauses in (1-3) with a name or proper noun whose identity is already established.

As I understand it, it's usually ungrammatical to use 'that' in a non-defining relative clause.  Given that the relative clauses in (1-3) are not defining, are not restrictive, and do not form a consituent with their antecedent, why is using *that* not a problem when the relative clause is in a cleft sentence?

Also aren't these relative clauses providing extra information?<sup>+</sup>

---

**Edit note:**

<sup>+</sup>In my original question I assumed that these relative clauses in (1-3) provide additional information. However, as pointed out in comments and in @DW256's answer, **they  aren't**.

Comment: Why is sentence 2 in your list? No *who* substitution there.

Comment: @nnnnnn As you mentioned, there is 'that' used instead of 'who' which is a substitution; this is why it is in the list...

Comment: Why do you say that these are nondefining relative clauses? Many people would say that they are defining.

Comment: Because of the same reason why the following sentences is so:  'William Kellogg, whose name has become a famous breakfast foods brand-name, had some weird ideas about raising children'.  It's clear that who Rob is. Do I think wrongly?

Comment: I prefer *that* for *which* in restrictive clauses, but not instead of *who*. In #1, you want to use that for who, which I wouldn't do.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No, I would use 'who' instead of 'that'. These are 'copy-paste' sentences from the Web site which I cited in the question.

Comment: If the relative clause modified "Rob", then I would agree with you, but I think that it modifies "it". The "original" sentence could be: "The person who ate my biscuits was Rob." The relative clause gets extraposed: "The person was Rob who ate my biscuits." And then a pronoun replaces the subject: "It was Rob who ate my biscuits." Of course, others may analyze the sentence differently. (BTW, please use the "@" symbol to respond to comments; I happened to stumble on your reply by accident.)

Comment: @orhantorun I don't know why you say they are non-defining relatives; They **are** defining relative clause, so "that" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan In clefts, the relative clause is not a modifier; it doesn't combine with its antecedent to form a syntactic constituent.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan The *it* in *it*-clefts does is a dummy element and does not refer. For that reason it cannot be modified.

Comment: I see people vote to close the question because of lack of details. Unfortunately, I can't provide more as there are none; I already cited the source. These are the original sentences, not fragments.

Comment: @BillJ I think this is the point; if they're defining relative clauses or not. You say they are not but I don't see any reasons for that except the absence of commas. For instance, if the sentence 'My brother Ben, who lives in Hong 
Kong, is an architect' contains an extra information clause then I don't see any reasons 'It was Rob who ate my biscuits' doesn't. Both speakers know who Rob is.

Comment: No, I said they **are** defining! The relative clauses in clefts are **always** defining, no exception, "It was Rob [who ate my biscuits]" is defining. It's part of the message, defining who ate my biscuit. To say it's non-defining makes no sense.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, as I noted, "others may analyze this sentence differently".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think that it's fine if you don't consider the relative clause to modify "it". I was just showing one reason why it might be considered defining.

Comment: Sentence 2 doesn't have *that* instead of *who*. You couldn't use *who* in that sentence at all. So again, why include that sentence in your list?

Comment: @nnnnnn I consider sentence 2 as a non-defining relative clause as already stated in the question, thus I say 'that' used as a constitution here, as already stated I made a copy-paste from the source without changing anything. Since you claim that it's incorrect to use 'who' in the second sentence, that might lead us to the answer. I paraphrased my first answer to you, the third will be the same.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Nonsense! Read **carefully** the last para of the OP's question and you'll see that they're asking about why we can use  _that_ in clefts but not in non-defining r/c's. Of course not all integrated r/cs are defining but for the sake of the OP,  I''m happy to use the term they chose, i.e 'defining', which virtually all integrated r/c's are.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I do like that part of your description which likens *it*-clefts to extraposition. I agree the two are very similar and the relative clause does have many (if not all) of the semantic import of an extraposed subject.

Comment: @BillJ In a defining relative clause, the antecedent is unclear and the relative clause identifies (or 'defines') who that entity is. Notice that the relative clause is defining, not the antecedent. It is this aspect of the pragmatics/semantics which prevents our using names or already identified entities as antecedent. Consider, assuming that you only have one father: *I met your father that bought me a drink* which is infelicitous. In an *it*-cleft, it is the entity described in the relative clause whose identity is unknown and it is the so-called antecedent, not the RC, which is 'defining'.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. If you still don't get it, consider that the OP is using the term 'non-defining' (vs 'definlng') for what you and I would call 'integrated' vs 'supplementary'. I may be wrong, but I doubt if the OP is aware of this somewhat more advanced way of looking at relative clauses.

Comment: 1) Everyone needs to stop arguing in the comments. (Some of what's been said should be made into its own answer). 2) I'm not locking edits. The old revisions are there if we really need them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it would be questionable to put a comma after the foregrounded element in the clefts. With a supplementary relative clause, this is always possible and usually advisable.

> ? It was Rob, that/who ate my biscuits.
>
> ? It was my biscuits, that/which Rob ate.
>
> ? Was it Rob, that/who ate my biscuits?

Clefts are an information packaging construction, which means that they are different ways of stating:

> Rob ate my biscuits.

His eating of the biscuits in the canonical version is not supplementary information, so, although possibly non-defining, it should not be viewed as supplementary in the cleft construction.

There are four types of relative clauses:

> The man **who won** died several days later. [integrated]
>
> Her mother, **who we haven't seen in years**, attended the party as
> well. [supplementary]
>
> It was Rob **who ate my biscuits**. [cleft]
>
> **What he wanted** was a fresh start. [fused]

Comment: It would also be useful to mention that the relative clause in a cleft is not a modifier. It does not form a constituent with its antecedent.

Comment: Thank you DW256. The problem is if you use a comma you can't use 'that' in this sentence: 'It was Rob, that/who ate my biscuits'. Because it is incorrect to use commas if it's not an extra information clause and if it's an extra information clause it's wrong to use 'that' as a substitution for who. See unit 95 (p.190) in English Grammar in Use, Murphy (5th edition). This is mutually exclusive.

Comment: @orhantorun Exactly - it's not an 'extra information clause', which is made clear by the general inadmissibility of the comma in clefts, and hence there is no restriction against using 'that'.

Comment: @orhantorun I suggest you take on board what DW256 tells you. The clauses are defining; they are an essential part of the information being conveyed. They are not modifiers as such, but they are **dependents**, thus integrated, into their respective matrix clauses. There is no such thing as a non-defining relative clause in a cleft construction.

Comment: @BillJ These are not defining - as DW256 has admitted may be the case in their post! These are "defined" relative clauses where the function of the so-called antecedent and the relative clause are reversed! That's why we can use names as so-called antecedents here.

Comment: @DW256 You are right, but it is not presented this way in the literature. However, it's not clear what counts and what doesn't when it comes to 'extra information.' I think your answer would be much better, more informative for the people reading (especially the commenters, many of whom need it) and more interesting in general if it started off by showing the many senses in which the OP is correct, and then presenting the useful information that you do which can help in some sense to explain the OP's data.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Virtually all integrated relatives are 'defining' (GKP confirms this) but I doubt if the OP is aware of (or understands) that. For the sake of the OP, (who probable doesn't know about the integrated vs supplement contrast) I'm happy to talk of defining relative clauses in clefts, as the OP does. In other words, it's about using terminology that the OP uses/understands.

Comment: They, like GKP, understand what "defining" means. GKP would agree that whilst integrated relative clauses are usually defining, these aren't!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The OP doesn't know about integrated vs supplemental, but only defining/non-defining, which at their level is permissible, so just leave it at that.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. To repeat my comment in the OP's thread, the r/c's in clefts are integrated, Quote from RDH/GKP on R/C's in clefts: **"The relative clause is of the integrated type"**. How much clearer can it be?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. In any case, the term 'defining' is not important. It's all about using "that" in r/c's in clefts but not in non-defining relatives. A simple answer was all that was needed.